# Filter without an "Apply" button behavior

Tags: filter, dropdown, selection, options

I have a filter that will automatically display the results without having to click on an "Apply" button. This isn't going to be an issue with our system since we're able to display results fast.

We'd like the user to be able to select all available options, but the problem is, since the results are automatically shown, what happens if the user deselects all options? Then the results will just be empty? Does it make sense for it to work that way?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Some multiple filters work the other way around: they show all possible items at startup and when clicking on each filter, the unfiltered ones disappear. The button `All options` is replaced by `Reset` or `Clear all`.

[image: multi-filter]

<sub>*Example demo [mixitup-multifilter](https://www.bostoen.be/assets/bower_components/mixitup-multifilter/demos/checkboxes/)*</sub>

Answer (score 0):

If the user deselects all options, then no filters are applied, and all results are shown. You could tweak "All Options" to say "Select All" to avoid the tension of having "All Options" deselected but showing all results.

Comment: So selecting all and not selecting any one option yield the same results, correct?

Comment: Almost! This would assume that all of your items belong to at least one listed filter category. If you select all filters and there are items that aren't tagged with a category, they wouldn't be displayed. It might be hard for users to intuit that, though, so you would want an Uncategorized category to make sure everything's included.